# customize hyphenation

Tags: hyphenation

I finish writing my article in english, but I think there are many hyphenations, this makes the document a bit ugly. my question: how prevent hyphenation throughout the document, and propose to latex, the words to cut. 
I use the `\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}` , in this case, I could not impose hyphenations where I want. 
I use two columns, normally I work on the model of Elsevier, I made some changes, here is the preamble:

```
\documentclass[final,5p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{ecrc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
```

your ideas please. thank you ...

Comment: Are you using a two column format?

Comment: Please tell us a bit more about your document: Which language is it in, how wide are the columns of text, and do you use a package such as `babel` that may affect TeX's hyphenation decisions? If the current setting produces too many line breaks with hyphenated words, what would be an acceptable number?

Comment: Try to set `\hyphenpenalty = 1000` instead of using `\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}` and see whether the result is better.

Comment: `\hyphenpenalty = 1000` is a simple and perfect solution ... thank you deeply sir karlkoeller ... I also Thank Mr. Egreg and Mr. Mico ...

Answer (score 4):

You can try increasing the penalty for hyphenation from its default value of 50 to something like 1000 that would discourage hyphenation without disabling it completely like `\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}` would do.

It's probably better to add also a setting for `\emergencystretch`, so I'd say

```
\hyphenpenalty=1000
\emergencystretch=5em
```

in the document preamble.